# AMS1117-3.3 over-heating and blow up way below max current

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, heat

I am designing a circuit for my home automation system. To give a gist, I have a 12V 3.5A supply. I need to operate multiple loads off it.
One of the Loads is a ESp12E module.

Esp12e module ----- Max current pull = 350mA. Voltage = 3.3V.

For this purpose, I am using a regulator AMS1117-3.3
Following is my circuit diagram:
[image]

My Problem is, with this connection, the AMS1117-3.3 regulator is heating up and hence blowing up. I have read the datasheet and it says "Max output current = 1A"

What can be the problem?

Comment: It also has a maximum power dissipation rating that you seem to be exceeding. Linearly regulating 12V down to 3.3V means getting rid of a lot of excessive power.

Comment: Yes, 12V to 3.3V at 500mA means dissipating nearly 45W of power

Comment: @shantanu no, 4.35W. But that is more than a AMS1117-3.3 can deal with.

Comment: Im sorry. I ment 4.5W. forgot the decimal. So the only solution being using a TO223 package with a heat sink

Comment: Or a DC-DC step down regulator. These step down the voltage without wasting power as heat.

Comment: @SteveG: "... without wasting *as much* power as heat." With efficiencies on the order of 80-90%, you can still expect a switching regulator to waste about 10-20% of the output power. Which would be about 120-240 mW in this case, a huge improvement over the linear regulator.

Comment: but won't a switching regulator be much more costlier than a linear regulator?

Comment: @shantanu a) you need to compare the cost to cooler-less step down to linear regulator with a cooler.  b) define "much costlier"; I don't know what you pay for your AMS1117-3.3. c)  And maybe you should factor in the cost of wasted power, too, depending on your application.

Comment: @shantanu  I don't know where you buy your AMS1117 (I can't even buy them), or how much they cost, but a MC33063AD [can be had for around 0.20€ in small quantities](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/mc33063ad/voltage-regulators-dc-dc-circuits/texas-instruments/), for example. Yes, you'll need as many capacitors as your current design has, you'll need one diode, three resistors and an inductor, but for your use case, these would add up to a total of probably less than 0.20€ themselves. So, excluding manufacturing cost, your switch mode power supply would cost around 0.40€ and use less PCB space

Comment: @shantanu The cheapest linear regulator I can find [on mouser](http://eu.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Power-Management-ICs/Linear-Voltage-Regulators/_/N-6j76qZscv7?P=1z0w877Z1z0wd8oZ1z0wd73Z1z0wd5eZ1z0wa2eZ1yzvdtpZ1yzvdudZ1yzvdtgZ1yzvdu7Z1yzvduaZ1yzvdtxZ1yzvdsg&Ns=Pricing%7c0) that does a fixed 12V->3.3V, >=400mA costs 0.51€; so it's even more expensive, not including the head sink that has to have substantial size!

Comment: @shantanu also, to be frank, at your level of knowledge, you're not going to produce a couple thousands of these devices. So don't care about saving 0.05€ per piece. That makes no sense for small series, prototypes and private hobbies.

Answer (score 10):

**Summary**: go with a buck regulator which saves power and space.

If linear regulator is still a choice, due to the huge voltage difference between input and output (12-3.3 = 8.7 V) and the current through linear regulator ( 350 mA) you would see a power dissipation of about 8.7 * 0.35 = more than 4 W!!. This huge power is dissipated as heat.

Adding a big heatsink, will help the regulator to live the huge heat dissipation. Also. Chose the linear with thermal packaging which has got good (lesser thermal resistance) thermal characteristics.

Another option is to bring down the voltage to 5 V or 4.5 V using switching regulator. Placing the linear after the switching regulator now will be dissipating lesser heat because it has to drop lesser voltage across it.

Relevant application note from TI :  Google "SLVA 462"

> Understanding Thermal Dissipation and Design of a Heatsink

[refresher 2](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/217)